# How to add a header to an OkHttp request object that has been built?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I want to add a header to a OkHttp request object that has already been built. Should I be calling `newBuilder()` on request? What does `newBuilder()` do?

Comment: Read the source, Luke.  https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/0ac2471d0678dfa9d535fbb13a546134dc2b3089/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Request.java#L93

Comment: It sounds like you may want an Interceptor.  You can easily insert your header via newBuilder() in an Interceptor.

Answer (score 15):

If this is just a one-time header insertion on a `Request`, then sure:
`request.newBuilder().addHeader("header-name", "value").build();`

If you want to do this for all `Request`s in your `OkHttpClient`, use an interceptor:

```
private static final class AddHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    request = request.newBuilder().addHeader("header-name", "value").build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
  }
}
```

As for what newBuilder() does, read the source. :) https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/0ac2471d0678dfa9d535fbb13a546134dc2b3089/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Request.java#L93